# SQLZoo Hard Questions #12 AdventureWorks Assessments

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by

I'm a rookie in the Database world, I just started learning and found SQLZoo website to be very helpful.
I got stuck on this question from in the AdventureWorks database.

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/AdventureWorks_hard_questions

12.For each order show the SalesOrderID and SubTotal calculated three ways: 
  A) From the SalesOrderHeader 
  B) Sum of OrderQty*UnitPrice 
  C) Sum of OrderQty*ListPrice

For some reason I can't figure this one out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
   A.SalesOrderID,
   A.SubTotal AS SubTotalA,
   B.SubtotalB,
   C.SubtotalC 
FROM SalesOrderHeader A
JOIN
(
   SELECT SUM(sodB.OrderQty*sodB.UnitPrice) AS SubTotalB 
   FROM SalesOrderDetail sodB 
   JOIN ProductAW pawB 
   ON pawB.ProductID=sodB.ProductID
   GROUP BY sodB.SalesOrderID
)  AS B
JOIN
(
   SELECT SUM(sodC.OrderQty*pawC.ListPrice) AS SubTotalC 
   FROM SalesOrderDetail sodC 
   JOIN ProductAW pawC 
   ON pawC.ProductID=sodC.ProductID
   GROUP BY sodC.SalesOrderID
 )  AS C
```

For some reason when I run either SELECT statements B or C individually outside JOIN I get the results I was expecting, but when I place then inside JOIN all values for SubTotalB or Subtotal C are repeated showing the same result as the first row value.

```
SELECT SUM(sodC.OrderQty*pawC.ListPrice) AS SubTotalC 
   FROM SalesOrderDetail sodC 
   JOIN ProductAW pawC 
   ON pawC.ProductID=sodC.ProductID
   GROUP BY sodC.SalesOrderID
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(sodC.OrderQty*pawC.ListPrice) AS SubTotalC 
   FROM SalesOrderDetail sodC 
   JOIN ProductAW pawC 
   ON pawC.ProductID=sodC.ProductID
   GROUP BY sodC.SalesOrderID
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the final solution:

```
SELECT 
   A.SalesOrderID,
   A.SubTotal AS SubTotalA,
   B.SubtotalB,
   C.SubtotalC 
FROM SalesOrderHeader A
JOIN
(
   SELECT SUM(sodB.OrderQty*sodB.UnitPrice) AS SubTotalB, sodB.SalesOrderID 
   FROM SalesOrderDetail sodB 
   JOIN ProductAW pawB 
   ON pawB.ProductID=sodB.ProductID
   GROUP BY sodB.SalesOrderID
)  AS B
ON A.SalesOrderID = B.SalesOrderID
JOIN
(
  SELECT SUM(sodC.OrderQty*pawC.ListPrice) AS SubTotalC, sodC.SalesOrderID 
  FROM SalesOrderDetail sodC 
  JOIN ProductAW pawC 
  ON pawC.ProductID=sodC.ProductID
  GROUP BY sodC.SalesOrderID
)  AS C
ON A.SalesOrderID = C.SalesOrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outer query doesn't have any ON clauses. This will cause each record from table B to be set against each record in Table A. So, if table A had 5 records, and table B had 5 Records, you'd have 25 total records. Then of course all of these records are being multiplied against table C as well. all of the AB records would be set against each record in table C.

I added a ProductID to each of the sub queries SELECT statements, and then added an ON statement to each of the JOINS in the outer query to join on matching ProductIDs. I hope this is what you were going for.

```
SELECT 
   A.SalesOrderID,
   A.SubTotal AS SubTotalA,
   B.SubtotalB,
   C.SubtotalC 
FROM SalesOrderHeader A
JOIN
(
   SELECT SUM(sodB.OrderQty*sodB.UnitPrice) AS SubTotalB,
   pawB.ProductID
   FROM SalesOrderDetail sodB 
   JOIN ProductAW pawB 
   ON pawB.ProductID=sodB.ProductID
   GROUP BY sodB.SalesOrderID
)  AS B 
ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
JOIN
(
   SELECT SUM(sodC.OrderQty*pawC.ListPrice) AS SubTotalC,
   pawC.ProductID
   FROM SalesOrderDetail sodC 
   JOIN ProductAW pawC 
   ON pawC.ProductID=sodC.ProductID
   GROUP BY sodC.SalesOrderID
 )  AS C
ON A.ProductID = C.ProductID
```

Comment: After you pointed out that the outer query was missing the ON clause I also realized that B and C queries were missing a reference to their SalesOrderID.                                                  I added sob.SalesOrderID & sodC.SalesOrderID to your solution and now it works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I love that site, but I wish there was a place to compare answers because I just want to know if my queries are done in the best way.  This is what I came up with for the same problem:

```sql
SELECT soh.salesorderid, 
    soh.subtotal AS "SubTotal A", 
    SUM(sod.orderqty * sod.unitprice) AS "SubTotal B", 
    SUM(sod.orderqty * paw.ListPrice) AS "SubTotal C" 
FROM SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN SalesOrderDetail sod (ON sod.salesorderid = soh.salesorderid)
JOIN ProductAW paw (ON paw.productid = sod.productid)
GROUP BY soh.salesorderid
```

I'm still learning too so if anyone wants to chime in and let me know how I can improve it, please do.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the results using aggregate function and GROPING. Using `MAX(Soh.SubTotal)` considering there will be only one unique row in SalesOrderHeader table. Rest of the calculation can be done within an aggregate function.

```
SELECT Soh.SalesOrderID
     , MAX(Soh.SubTotal) as SubTotal
     , COALESCE(SUM(Sod.OrderQty * Sod.UnitPrice), 0) as [Sum of OrderQty*UnitPrice]
     , COALESCE(SUM(Sod.OrderQty * Prd.ListPrice),0) as [Sum of OrderQty*ListPrice] 
FROM   SalesOrderHeader as Soh 
       INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail as Sod ON (Soh.SalesOrderID = Sod.SalesOrderID)
       INNER JOIN Product as Prd ON (Prd.ProductID = Sod.ProductID)
GROUP BY Soh.SalesOrderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer:

```
select soh.salesOrderId,soh.SubTotal,sum(sod.OrderQty*sod.UnitPrice), 
sum(sod.OrderQty*p.ListPrice) from SalesOrderHeader soh
inner join SalesOrderDetail sod on soh.SalesOrderId=sod.SalesOrderId
inner join Product p on p.ProductId=sod.productId
group by soh.salesOrderId,soh.SubTotal;
```

Top voted answer is:

1. Overcomplicated

   - subqueries are not needed, they just make the query longer to read
2. Worse off in performance

   - Accessing the same table repeatedly in search for the same rows, just processed differently.
3. Doesn't work on adventureworks anymore.

   - there is no table called "ProductAw", it's "Product" now, my guess would be they changed it

This solution is the same as @Vishwanath Dalvi 's minus using coalesce as it's not needed.
Also the same as @AruN's, this is really just a response to the comment on his answer(asking to provide rationale) so this should have been a comment on his answer.
Unfortunately I just started on stackOverflow and can't comment :(

Answer (score -1):

```
select t1.SalesOrderID ID,t1.SubTotal SUBTOTAL,
sum(t2.OrderQty*t2.UnitPrice) SUBTOTAL
,sum(t2.OrderQty*t3.ListPrice) SUBTOTAL
from SalesOrderHeader t1 join SalesOrderDetail t2 on t1.SalesOrderID=t2.SalesOrderID join ProductAW t3 on t3.productid=t2.productid
group by t1.SalesOrderID,t1.Subtotal
```

Comment: Please edit your answer. Add your code in code-tags for better readability and add descriptions what you did and why and how this fixes OP's problem.